# Microsoft.AspNet.Identity - customize POCO class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am struggling to add a few fields to the standard ApplicationUser object with the code below. I have successfully run Migrations and i can see the database scheme is updated with the new fields in the database. I followed the tutorial at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594

```
public class ApplicationUser : User
{

    public string LegacyPassword { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public bool Activated { get; set; }

}
```

The problem i experience is now when i try execute registration such as :

```
 var u = new Test.Models.ApplicationUser() { UserName = userName, DateCreated = System.DateTime.Now, PassHash = "" };
            IdentityResult result = manager.Users.CreateLocalUser(u, Password.Text);
```

I get the following error when CreateLocalUser() executes...:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType 'Test.Models.ApplicationUser'.

I have tried recreating the migrations about 5/6 times and started a brand new project as well but i cannot get past this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think it might be having trouble mapping to properties like the UserName property of the inherited User class, check your syntax for that type of mapping (i.e., User.UserName = ...).

Comment: The problem was something strange in the RC version. The problem went away in RTM...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using version from the VS2013 release, change as follows.

`public class ApplicationUser : User`

to

`public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser`

Comment: I have added your answer as correct. I was using RC1 this problems seems to have been fixed in final.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens in projects that have been generated in the RC version of Visual Studio 2013.

Go to your projects nuget packages folder, you will notice that  a lot of them including EntityFramework are RC version.

Update all nuget packages to the latest release versions will solve the problem. (Note that some code changes will be required).

EDIT: Installing `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` was also required.